# Can't connect to pusher with react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, error-handling, pusher, pusher-js

Hello i am new to react native and im trying to create a realtime chat application using pusher-js so i installed the package **npm install pusher-js @react-native-community/netinfo** and put the following code in my useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('REDACTED', {
        cluster:"eu"});

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    
}, [])
```

and im getting this in the console
[Link of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moUJe.png)

Im using react-native run-android to run and im using a physical device.
Thanks in advance for all the help you can provide.

Comment: I've removed your application keys - you should also consider rotating the keys in the Pusher Dashboard to prevent unauthorised use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you given your app the necessary permissions to access the network? To do so you will need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

to your android manifest.
See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting

Comment: tnx it is working now your answer was part of the solution i also disabled the debugger for it to work